# Android app on Chrome using ARC, keep back button on top enabled

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

[developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices)

The ARC allows you to execute native android apps through the chrome browser by wrapping a chrome app around it.(As far as I can tell)

I am re-factoring an Android app to work well on Chrome. The first thing I need to do is to make the back arrow enabled at all times on the top left as shown below.
[image]

This is the program that allows Native android apps to run through chrome. I think the answer to my question lies somewhere in "Additional Metadata", or in the source code?

[image]

Comment: Because the question is incomprehensible. What do [Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) have to do with it? How a [presumably native] Android app can "work well on Chrome"?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices

Comment: I think a chrome app wraps the apk somehow allowing the App Runtime for Chrome (Beta), or ARC to execute a native android app.

Comment: I am unsure how any of this in incomprehensible, please explain @Xan

Comment: It is incomprehensible because the ARC part is not explained well - for instance, I missed it. It is curious though, the google-chrome-app tag is a bad fit but I don't think there is a tag for ARC yet. I'll look into it.

Comment: "Android app on chrome using ARC" is in the title. I didn't think I would have to prove the existence of a technology before asking a question about it.

Comment: "ARC" was the first tag I tried, does not exist.

Comment: Well then, I shall create the tag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74362/discussion-between-theyouthis-and-xan).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add {"disableAutoBackButton": "true"} to the metadata. That will enable the back button within an activity. I've found that with my app that has multiple activities, though, it doesn't work to return to my main activity from my settings activity. It could be that I'm doing something wrong with the way I'm handling activities, I guess, but it works on all physical devices.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to work well with how I am managing activities.

Comment: Does this also apply to chrome apps? I am wondering if it is appropriate to include the chrome app tag in future questions related to ARC?

Answer (score 3):

```
{"sleepOnBlur":false,"disableAutoBackButton":true}
```

please supply the above metadata before you download the zip or launch app from the arc welder

the first param prevents excessive pause/resume and also supposed to fix short black screen flash occurring occassionally in some of the apps.

the second params adds persistance back button on top left hence helping to avoid extra code required because of absence of back button in some screens(mostly the first screen)